# How can I add a value to a collection only if the value doesn't already exist?

Tags: ravendb

In ravendb, I'm trying to address a race condition where many urls can be added to a single document at the same time. In order to do this safely (and not create duplicate entries in the collection), I need the condition check and array push to happen atomically at the database. For example, the structure might look like this:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Urls { get; set; }
}
```

Assume all three of these operations happen asynchronously:

```
AddValue("foo");
AddValue("bar");
AddValue("foo");
```

I was looking at Patch, but I'm not seeing how to add in the condition. Could someone show me an example of how I might do this?

**Update**

Here is what I'm currently using

```
var listing = _session.Query<ListingData>()
    .Where(l => l.ListingId == listingId && l.OwnerId == userId)
    .ToList().SingleOrDefault();

if (listing == null)
    return DataResult.NotFound;

_session.Advanced.Patch(
    listing,
    l => l.PhotoUrls,
    urls => urls.Add(url));

_session.SaveChanges();
```

This seems to work for now if everything goes perfectly, but if there were cases were, for example, a application-side retry based on a false negative were to occur, then I think I would end up with duplicates because

- There's a round trip I have to do in order to get the entity/id
- The operation simply adds the value without checking to see if it exists first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a patch script.

```
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
{    
    var listing = _session.Query<ListingData>()
      .Where(l => l.ListingId == listingId && l.OwnerId == userId)
      .ToList().SingleOrDefault();

    session.Advanced.Defer(new PatchCommandData(
       id: listing.ListingId,
       changeVector: null,
       patch: new PatchRequest
       {
          Script = @"
             if (this.PhotoUrls.includes(url))
                   throw ‘Url already exists’;
             this.PhotoUrls.push($newUrl);
          ",
          Values =
          {
              ["newUrl"] = "The Url to add"
          }
       },
       patchIfMissing: null));

    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

See:

1. https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/csharp/client-api/operations/patching/single-document#non-typed-session-api
2. https://github.com/ravendb/book/blob/v4.0/Ch04/Ch04.md#patching-documents-and-concurrent-modifications

Comment: Looks like `.includes()` isn't supported. I was able to replace it with `if(this.PhotoUrls.indexOf($newUrl) == -1) this.PhotoUrls.push($newUrl)` I'm super new to RavenDb, and I didn't realize I could write vanilla JS in there like that. Just opened a new world. Thanks!

Comment: oh - yes - that's right - RavenDB uses **Jint**, an open source JavaScript interpreter that is supporting ECMAScript 5.1. - while includes() is ECMAScript 6. See :  
[https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/Csharp/server/kb/javascript-engine](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.1/Csharp/server/kb/javascript-engine)